# C++ take first 8 symbols from a string

Tags: c++, string, function, for-loop

The user inputs a text, then I check whether that string can be divided by 8

```
if(text.length()%8==0)
```

If yes, I take the quotient.

```
int sk = text.length()/8;
```

And so I need to take each 8 symbols from that sentence and convert to a new different symbol. For example if the sentence is 1234567890123456 it has to be divided to 2 different symbols. 12345678 = A and 90123456 = B

To do that I know I should use `for loop`
I've done this:

```
if(text.length()%8==0){
            sk = text.length()/8;
            for(int m=1;m<=sk;m++){
                //change the text
            }
}
```

So, my question is, what to write down in that `for loop` in order to see the desired results?

-Thank you

Comment: What have you tried to do? Did you look into the `std::string` docs to find functions that could help you? What, specifically, are you not managing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `replace` method from `std::string`:

```
if(text.length()%8==0){
        sk = text.length()/8;
        for(int m=1;m<=sk;m++){
            text.replace(sk, sk+8, newString);
        }
}
```

Of course there are some checks you'll need to perform.